# Problema a fazer refresh de quantidade carrinho de compras C#

Tags: c#, session, asp, gridview

Ao fazer o refresh da quantidade já no carrinho de compras, apenas consigo fazer o refresh da quantidade de um produto, se tiver 2 produtos no carrinho não consigo fazer refresh a um deles.

Imaginemos que o 1º produto tem 5 unidades e o 2º produto tem 1 unidade, se quisermos mudar a quantidade do 2º produto para 4 unidades não é possível, apenas é possível para 5 unidades, ou seja se quiser mudar a quantidade de um produto, todos os produtos têm o que ter o mesmo número de quantidade. Já tentei várias formas mas não consegui resolver o erro.

Código:

```
ImageButton lnksender = (ImageButton)sender;
            Session["IDCarrinho"] = Convert.ToInt32(lnksender.CommandArgument);
            try
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow di in GridViewManage.Rows)
                {
                    TextBox txtCarrinhoQuantidade = (TextBox)di.FindControl("txtCarrinhoQuantidade");

                    if (txtCarrinhoQuantidade.Text == "0")
                    {
                        string stringconn = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                        BLL.BD.backoffice oDB = new BLL.BD.backoffice(stringconn);
                        int num = oDB.EliminarCarrinhoNo(Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDCarrinho"]));
                        FormView FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho = Page.Master.FindControl("FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho") as FormView;
                        FormView FormViewTotalCarrinho = Page.Master.FindControl("FormViewTotalCarrinho") as FormView;
                        FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho.DataBind();
                        FormViewTotalCarrinho.DataBind();
                        GridViewManage.DataBind();
                        int rowCount = GridViewManage.Rows.Count;

                        if (rowCount == 0)
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("Produtos.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string stringconn = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                        BLL.BD.backoffice oDB = new BLL.BD.backoffice(stringconn);
                        int num = oDB.AlterarQuantidade(Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDCarrinho"]), Convert.ToInt32(txtCarrinhoQuantidade.Text));
                        FormView FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho = Page.Master.FindControl("FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho") as FormView;
                        FormView FormViewTotalCarrinho = Page.Master.FindControl("FormViewTotalCarrinho") as FormView;
                        FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho.DataBind();
                        FormViewTotalCarrinho.DataBind();
                        if (num == 1)
                        {
                            FormView FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho1 = Page.Master.FindControl("FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho") as FormView;
                            FormView FormViewTotalCarrinho1 = Page.Master.FindControl("FormViewTotalCarrinho") as FormView;
                            FormViewQuantidadeCarrinho1.DataBind();
                            FormViewTotalCarrinho1.DataBind();
                            GridViewManage.DataBind();
                            Response.Redirect("Carrinho.aspx");

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

Stored P e BLL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AlterarQuantidade]
    @IDCarrinho int,
    @Quantidade int

AS

    UPDATE Carrinho SET Quantidade = @Quantidade WHERE IDCarrinho = @IDCarrinho

RETURN
```

BLL:

```
public int AlterarQuantidade(int IDCarrinho, int Quantidade)
            {
                SqlConnection ligacao = getConexao();
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("AlterarQuantidade", ligacao);
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameteridcarrinho = new SqlParameter("@IDCarrinho", SqlDbType.Int);
                parameteridcarrinho.Value = IDCarrinho;
                comando.Parameters.Add(parameteridcarrinho);

                SqlParameter parameterquant = new SqlParameter("@Quantidade", SqlDbType.Int);
                parameterquant.Value = Quantidade;
                comando.Parameters.Add(parameterquant);


                int num = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                closeConexao(ligacao);
                if (num == 1)
                {
                    return 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
```

**EDIT**: O problema de passar o ID Carrinho e ID produto está resolvido, o problema de momento é a textbox da quantidade na gridview, quando mudo a quantidade do 2º produto por exemplo, que está na 2ª row, ele apenas considera a quantidade do 1º produto, ou seja está sempre a ir buscar a quantidade do produto de cima, e não considera a da selected row.

O problema é daqui:

`TextBox txtCarrinhoQuantidade = (TextBox)di.FindControl("txtCarrinhoQuantidade");`

Comment: Como está sua instrução de UPDATE na tabela? Pela sua descrição, aparenta estar faltando a cláusula WHERE, ou estar definida incorretamente.

Comment: Veja a resposta editada em cima.

Comment: Já sei qual o problema, o problema é que não estou a passar o ID do Produto quando clico na Image Button para actualizar o cart.
Como poderei passar o ID do Produto, do selected row?

Já tentei de várias formas mas sem sucesso.

Estou a enviar o ID Carrinho desta forma:

`protected void imgBtnUpdateCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton lnksender = (ImageButton)sender;
            Session["IDCarrinho"] = Convert.ToInt32(lnksender.CommandArgument);`

Como posso enviar o ID do carrinho e o ID do Produto da selected row ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: O problema é realmente a textbox que está na gridview onde se insere a quantidad do produto, a textbox considerada é sempre a 1ª, logo o valor de quantidade dos restantes produtos é sempre igual ao 1º.
Como poderei verificar a cada row o valor da textbox?

A textbox está dentro de templatefield.

Comment: Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Não deveria conter um Where com a chave do produto?

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AlterarQuantidade] IDCarrinho int, Quantidade int 
    AS UPDATE Carrinho SET Quantidade = 500
    WHERE IDCarrinho = 1 
RETURN
```

onde 1 é o respectivo id de um carrinho existente.

Comment: Quando coloco

`UPDATE Carrinho SET Quantidade = @Quantidade WHERE IDCarrinho = @IDCarrinho AND IDProduto = @IDProduto`

E altero na BLL também, depois não faz nada, se tirar o IDProduto já actualiza mas apenas o 1º produto.

Comment: Tenta fazer direto no banco, pra ver se rola.

Comment: Sim aí desse jeito dá.

Comment: Alterou na Procedure?

Comment: Apenas na procedure?
Tenho que mudar no CB, e na BLL também, mas se alterar ele deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Coloca o valor direto na Procedure, só pra ver se vai bombar

Comment: Não percebi, poderia exemplificar?

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AlterarQuantidade]
    IDCarrinho int,
    Quantidade int

AS

    UPDATE Carrinho SET Quantidade = 500 WHERE IDCarrinho = 1

RETURN

onde 1 é o respectivo id de um carrinho existente

Comment: Sim funcionou colocando dessa forma.

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal seu problema se resolve com a procedure proposta pelo Guilherme?

Comment: Não se resolve.

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal, seu problema claramente está no WHERE, como já foi dito. Você precisa filtrar além do ID do carrinho, também o ID do produto que está sendo alterado. Trabalhe em cima dessa ideia.

Comment: Isso já foi feito, o problema é que quando altero a quantidade da textbox na gridview apenas é considerada a 1ª textbox, o problema está aí. O resto está feito, já está a considerar o ID Carrinho e ID Produto.

Comment: @JoelRodrigues actualizei a pergunta com mais detalhes do erro actual.